# Jupyter on docker cannot automatically open up browser when it executed

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I've had docker to use the jupyter notebook with tensorflow.
(My OS is window 10 so I use the Powershell.)

I want the jupyter to open the web browser automatically. When I try to initialize jupyter notebook.

For instance, I enter the command to start anaconda image (including tensorflow).

`> docker run -it  -v ~/tensorwork:/notebooks -p 8888:8888 anaconda3`

And activate tensorflow

`(base) root@e088a0e0e58e:/# conda activate tensorflow`

After entering tensorflow kernel mode, I execute jupyter notebook.

```
(tensorflow) root@e088a0e0e58e:/# jupyter notebook --ip '*' --allow-root
[I 14:47:00.827 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 4 kernels found
[W 14:47:01.080 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
[I 14:47:01.214 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
[I 14:47:01.219 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 14:47:01.265 NotebookApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
[W 14:47:01.265 NotebookApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named 'nbbrowserpdf'
[I 14:47:01.268 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /
[I 14:47:01.269 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 14:47:01.269 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 14:47:01.269 NotebookApp] http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/?token=55d0e39e50ff64ca52ab43516d06c96127704fb56de2d356
[I 14:47:01.269 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 14:47:01.270 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 14:47:01.275 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=55d0e39e50ff64ca52ab43516d06c96127704fb56de2d356
```

Execution of the jupyter notebook works well.
However, I manually enter the URL my browser to enter the notebook.

I guess this problem came from docker's feature. The container's file path needs to be connected to the local host so that jupyter can find the default web browser(chrome) that I use.

But how can I make it possible? I've already tried the editing config of jupyter notebook.

Before I execute jupyter notebook, I enter the command as following:

`jupyter notebook --generate-config`
`vim ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py # or use your favorite editor`
`c.NotebookApp.browser = u'chrome'`

(refer ; https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/oXjbKNMyP30)

But the jupyter still said it cannot find any web browser. Help me please :)

Comment: This is not possible. Usually this is just jupyter making a call out to open the default browser, but as there is no browser *in* the container (only on the host) then there is nothing it can do. You will have to go to the url manually.